# Python / Get unique tokens from a file with a exception

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp

I want to find the number of unique tokens in a file. For this purpose I wrote the below code:

```
splittedWords = open('output.txt', encoding='windows-1252').read().lower().split()
uniqueValues = set(splittedWords)

print(uniqueValues)
```

The output.txt file is like this:

```
Türkiye+Noun ,+Punc terörizm+Noun+Gen ve+Conj kitle+Noun imha+Noun silah+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Gen küresel+Adj düzey+Noun+Loc olus+Verb+Caus+PastPart+P3sg tehdit+Noun+Gen boyut+Noun+P3sg karsi+Adj+P3sg+Loc ,+Punc tüm+Det ülke+Noun+A3pl+Gen yay+Verb+Pass+Inf2+Gen önle+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg hedef+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Acc paylas+Verb+PastPart+P3pl ,+Punc daha+Noun güven+Noun+With ve+Conj istikrar+Noun+With bir+Num dünya+Noun düzen+Noun+P3sg için+PostpPCGen birlik+Noun+Loc çaba+Noun göster+Verb+PastPart+P3pl bir+Num asama+Noun+Dat gel+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc samimi+Adj ol+Verb+ByDoingSo arzula+Verb+Prog2+Cop .+Punc 
Ab+Noun ile+PostpPCNom gümrük+Noun Alan+Noun+P3sg+Loc+Rel kurumsal+Adj iliski+Noun+A3pl 
club+Noun toplanti+Noun+A3pl+P3sg 
Türkiye+Noun+Gen -+Punc At+Noun gümrük+Noun isbirlik+Noun+P3sg komite+Noun+P3sg ,+Punc Ankara+Noun Anlasma+Noun+P3sg+Gen 6+Num madde+Noun+P3sg uyar+Verb+When ortaklik+Noun rejim+Noun+P3sg+Gen uygula+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc ve+Conj gelis+Verb+Inf2+P3sg+Acc sagla+Verb+Inf1 üzere+PostpPCNom ortaklik+Noun Konsey+Noun+P3sg+Gen 2+Num /+Punc 69+Num sayili+Adj karar+Noun+P3sg ile+Conj teknik+Noun komite+Noun mahiyet+Noun+P3sg+Loc kur+Verb+Pass+Narr+Cop .+Punc 
nispi+Adj 
nisbi+Adj 
görece+Adj+With 
izafi+Adj 
obur+Adj
```

With this code I can get the unique tokens like Türkiye+Noun, Türkiye+Noun+Gen. But I want to get forexample Türkiye+Noun, Türkiye+Noun+Gen like only one token before the + sign. I only want Türkiye part. In the end Türkiye+Noun and Türkiye+Noun+Gen tokens needs to be same and only treated as a single unique token. I think I need to write regex for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow does the tokens you want include ',' (comma) for instance, or just the words?

Comment: Just words are okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the word you want is always the 1st in a list of `'+'`-joined words:

Split the splitted words at `+` and take the 0th one:

```
text = """Türkiye+Noun ,+Punc terörizm+Noun+Gen ve+Conj kitle+Noun imha+Noun silah+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Gen küresel+Adj düzey+Noun+Loc olus+Verb+Caus+PastPart+P3sg tehdit+Noun+Gen boyut+Noun+P3sg karsi+Adj+P3sg+Loc ,+Punc tüm+Det ülke+Noun+A3pl+Gen yay+Verb+Pass+Inf2+Gen önle+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg hedef+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Acc paylas+Verb+PastPart+P3pl ,+Punc daha+Noun güven+Noun+With ve+Conj istikrar+Noun+With bir+Num dünya+Noun düzen+Noun+P3sg için+PostpPCGen birlik+Noun+Loc çaba+Noun göster+Verb+PastPart+P3pl bir+Num asama+Noun+Dat gel+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc samimi+Adj ol+Verb+ByDoingSo arzula+Verb+Prog2+Cop .+Punc 
Ab+Noun ile+PostpPCNom gümrük+Noun Alan+Noun+P3sg+Loc+Rel kurumsal+Adj iliski+Noun+A3pl 
club+Noun toplanti+Noun+A3pl+P3sg 
Türkiye+Noun+Gen -+Punc At+Noun gümrük+Noun isbirlik+Noun+P3sg komite+Noun+P3sg ,+Punc Ankara+Noun Anlasma+Noun+P3sg+Gen 6+Num madde+Noun+P3sg uyar+Verb+When ortaklik+Noun rejim+Noun+P3sg+Gen uygula+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc ve+Conj gelis+Verb+Inf2+P3sg+Acc sagla+Verb+Inf1 üzere+PostpPCNom ortaklik+Noun Konsey+Noun+P3sg+Gen 2+Num /+Punc 69+Num sayili+Adj karar+Noun+P3sg ile+Conj teknik+Noun komite+Noun mahiyet+Noun+P3sg+Loc kur+Verb+Pass+Narr+Cop .+Punc 
nispi+Adj 
nisbi+Adj 
görece+Adj+With 
izafi+Adj 
obur+Adj """

splittedWords = text.lower().replace("\n"," ").split()
uniqueValues = set( ( s.split("+")[0] for s in splittedWords))

print(uniqueValues)
```

Output:

```
{'imha', 'çaba', 'ülke', 'arzula', 'terörizm', 'olus', 'daha', 'istikrar', 'küresel', 
 'sagla', 'önle', 'üzere', 'nisbi', 'türkiye', 'gelis', 'bir', 'karar', 'hedef', '2', 
 've', 'silah', 'kur', 'alan', 'club', 'boyut', '-', 'anlasma', 'iliski', 
 'izafi', 'kurumsal', 'karsi', 'ankara', 'ortaklik', 'obur', 'kitle', 'güven', 
 'uygula', 'ol', 'düzey', 'konsey', 'teknik', 'rejim', 'komite', 'gümrük', 'samimi', 
  'gel', 'yay', 'toplanti', '.', 'asama', 'mahiyet', 'ab', '69', 'için', 
 'paylas', '6', '/', 'nispi', 'dünya', 'at', 'sayili', 'görece', 'isbirlik', 'birlik', 
 ',', 'tüm', 'ile', 'düzen', 'uyar', 'göster', 'tehdit', 'madde'}
```

You might need to do some additional cleanup to remove things like

```
',' '6' '/'
```

**Split and remove anything thats just numbers or punctuation**

```
from string import digits, punctuation

remove=set(digits+punctuation)

splittedWords = text.lower().split()
uniqueValues = set( ( s.split("+")[0] for s in splittedWords))

# remove from set anything that only consists of numbers or punctuation
uniqueValues = uniqueValues - set ( x for x in uniqueValues if all(c in remove for c in x))
print(uniqueValues)
```

to get it as:

```
{'teknik', 'yay', 'göster','hedef', 'terörizm', 'ortaklik','ile', 'daha', 'ol', 'istikrar', 
 'paylas', 'nispi', 'üzere', 'sagla', 'tüm', 'önle', 'asama', 'uygula', 'güven', 'kur', 
 'türkiye', 'gel', 'dünya', 'gelis', 'sayili', 'ab', 'club', 'küresel', 'imha', 'çaba', 
 'olus', 'iliski', 'izafi', 'mahiyet', 've', 'düzey', 'anlasma', 'tehdit', 'bir', 'düzen', 
 'obur', 'samimi', 'boyut', 'ülke', 'arzula', 'rejim', 'gümrük', 'karar', 'at', 'karsi', 
 'nisbi', 'isbirlik', 'alan', 'toplanti', 'ankara', 'birlik', 'kurumsal', 'için', 'kitle', 
 'komite', 'silah', 'görece', 'uyar', 'madde', 'konsey'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split all the tokens you have now on "+" and take only the first one.

```
uniqueValues = set(map(lambda x: x.split('+')[0], splittedWords))
```

Here I use map. Map will apply the function (the lambda part) on all values of the splittedWords.